# Python Script taking a long time to run on large files

Tags: python

I am writing a python script to find the latest zip files in a given directory. I just finished to write it, but it's taking really long time to give the output on data that are >30 GB. It's taking ~45min to run. Any tips on how I can improve the performance of my script to run faster? I am using python 2.7 on a windows 10.

```
import os, glob
from datetime import datetime

def findZip_Dir_list(cwd):
    file_dirs = []
    for (dirname, dirs, files) in os.walk(cwd):
        for filename in files:
            if filename.endswith('.zip'):
                file_dirs.append(dirname)

     return file_dirs

cwd = os.getcwd()

zip_dirs = findZip_Dir_list(cwd)

new_dirs = []
for i in zip_dirs:
    if i not in new_dirs:
        new_dirs.append(i)

latest_zip = []
for j in new_dirs:

    list_of_files = glob.glob(j+'/*.zip')

    latest_zip.append(max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime))

for k in latest_zip:
    print k
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're going to need to show your code...

Comment: ...and the folder / file structure.

Comment: -Update: I just added my code. @DanielMessias

Comment: What's your problem? please include a clear problem statement IN YOUR POST.

Answer (score 1):

The best and simplest idea is to use [PyPy](https://pypy.org/).

It is an alternative python interpreter that is very optimized. However, if you use modules written in C that are not from the standard library, you won't be able to use them directly with PyPy.

Comment: I downloaded the zip file for Pypy, but I can't figure out how to install it and run it. Any suggestion  on how to do this? I am using windows 10 and python 2.7

Comment: You should see a pypy executable. Just launch the command:
`/path/to/pypy /path/to/your/script [arguments]`

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the code and the data it's working on, I can only guess, but if you only need to find the latest files, the running time should depend on the number of files in the directory, not their size. To get the last time of modification of a file, you can use `os.stat()` for example.

EDIT:
Ok, now that I see it, here are some things that could make it faster:

- in the function, make the file_dirs a set instead of a list, that way you can avoid duplicate elements
- if you already found a zip file in a directory, you can break the inner loop in the os.walk()
- if there won't be any duplicates, you can use that set directly, and don't need to make the new_dirs list (checking if an element is in a list is a O(n) operation, and that is what makes the code so slow)

Comment: I am very new to python to python and I tried to look up the how to use set and it looks like it doesn't support indexing. Can you please show me how I can use it here?

Comment: It's true that sets are not indexable, but they have an `__in__` method, so you can just use `for j in zip_dirs:`. The order of the elements will not necessarily be the same as they were added, but it will loop through all of them.

Comment: Thanks for this! I just added your suggestions looks like it is reducing like 5min. But still it's taking like ~40min, which I think is quite a long a time. Any other tips? Thanks is advance!

Answer (score 0):

The compiler used in python isn't the fastet (It isn't as close to the machine code compared too for example C), that's why C, C++, etc is used for programs that require better performance. Unfortunately I don't think you can improve the speed if not betting a faster/better performing computer.

Hope this explains it :)